# Getting data from the options page to the injected code

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension runs on an existing web page I do not control. I want to have an options page for it. What I haven’t figured out is how to get the option values from the injected code. `localStorage` isn’t shared, of course. I’ve tried using  sendRequest / addListener in both directions, although it would be much preferable to push values from the options page to the injected code than they other way ‘round.

At the beginning, I simply put the option checkboxes on the manipulated page (the one the code is injected into), and those checkboxes set values in `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.showStuff = !!$(evt.target).attr(‘checked’);
```

Then I check those values in the code:

```
if (localStorage.showStuff == ‘true’) { … }
```

I moved the checkbox code to the options page and had it do a `sendRequest` when the options changed, and had my injected code have a listener for the message, but it doesn’t get the messages (my background page does, but that doesn’t help me). I also tried having the injected code hand a callback to the options page, but the `sendResponse` object only seems to work for the duration of the notify handler (not surprising, but I had to give it a try).

Right now my manifest’s `permissions` lists the foreign page (`"http://example.com/*"`) and `“tab”`.

The one thing I know I can do is asynchronously query the options page via a callback, but the code doesn’t (and really can’t) work asynchronously without serious rewriting.

Any and all ideas welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

i'm new to chrome extensions but when i tried to write/read localstorage from both, background script and option page it worked perfectly.

i haven't tried native localstorage but chrome's storage api.

take a look at this

code A: (set)

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'key':'qwe'});
```

code B: (get)

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('key', function(response) {
    console.log(response); // 'qwe'
});
```

u could put either code A in the background and code B in the option page or the other way around.
they are using the same storage.

this works for me. i hope u'll get there too.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember is that only the background page is long-lived. The rest of the pieces of your chrome extension are transient (content scripts for the duration of the site navigation, options pages only while open, etc).

So you have to use messaging and save things using the background page. However, get ready for the storage API which should be landing soon. This will make things a lot easier for you!

Check it out [here](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.storage.html).

Comment: So if I understand you, this means that my options page should send messages to my background page about option changes, and the injected code should ask the background page for the values. In my case the injected code seems to live as long as the page I’m on, which is all I need, but in any case, that still leaves me with the query-vs.-asynchronous issue. But this information is helpful, I will try to apply it, thanks!